# Nodejs Require to see which client had exited

Tags: node.js

I connected through this nodejs code using telnet. When exiting from telnet, the 'end' event fires but does not show the remote address and port.

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(s) {

   console.log('CONNECT:' + s.remoteAddress + ':' + s.remotePort);

   s.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('DATA: ' + s.remoteAddress + ':' + s.remotePort);
      s.write('You said "' + data + '"');
   });

   s.on('end', function() {
      console.log('END: ' + s.remoteAddress + ':' + s.remotePort);
   });

   s.write('hello\r\n');
});

server.listen(8000, function() {
   console.log('Server started on port 8000');
});
```

On the server console, i get the following when I quit telnet

```
END: undefined:undefined disconnected
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `end` event is fired when the client has closed the connection. In that case, the default behaviour for `net.createServer` is to also close the connection (but see below), so there is no more `remoteAddress` and `remotePort` at the time your callback is called.

The easiest solution is to just store those values in a variable when the connection is created:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(s) {
  var address = s.remoteAddress;
  var port    = s.remotePort;
  ...
  s.on('end', function() {
    console.log('END: ' + address + ':' + port);
  });
});
```

Another option is to enable [`allowHalfOpen`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener), which will stop the server from closing the connection when the client has closed their side:

```
var server = net.createServer({ allowHalfOpen : true }, function(s) {
  ...
  s.on('end', function() {
    console.log('END: ' + s.remoteAddress + ':' + s.remotePort);
    s.end(); // !!! close the server side explicitly
  });
});
```